# Dart: How to check if List of Objects is a List of Strings/ints/bools

Tags: dart

For simple data types, you can use e.g.

```
object is String
```

to check whether an Object variable is of a more specific type.

But let's you have a List, but want to check if it is a List of Strings. Intuitively we might try

```
List list = ['string', 'other string'];
print(list is List<String>);
```

which returns false.

Similarly using the List.cast() method doesn't help, it will always succeed and only throw an error later on when using the list.

We could iterate over the entire list and check the type of each individual entry, but I was hoping there might be a better way.

Comment: `List` is a raw type which is equivalent to `List<dynamic>`. Declare your list with the complete generic type and you won't have this issue. https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-writing-incomplete-generic-types

Comment: Also, you can get warnings about using raw types if you add `strict-raw-types: true` in your `analysis_options.yaml` file as shown here https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#the-analysis-options-file

Comment: The issue for me, is that the List in question is returned by a function from a library whose type I cannot control. For example retrieving data using firebase realtime/firestore gives back the data as an Object?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other way. What you have is a `List<Object?>`/`List<dynamic>` (because the type is inferred from the variable type, which is a raw `List` type which gets instantiated to its bound). The list *currently* only contains `String` objects, but nothing prevents you from adding a `new Object()` to it.

So, the object itself doesn't know that it only contains strings, you have to look at each element to check that.

Or, when you create a list, just declare the variable as `List<String> list = ...;` or `var list = ...;`, then the object will be a `List<String>`.
If you are not the one creating the list, it's back to `list.every((e) => e is String)`.

Answer (score 0):

Each element of a List may be of any type BUT IF YOU ARE SURE that all elements have the same type this approach may be useful

```
bool listElementIs<T>(List l) {
  if (l.isEmpty) return true;
  try {
    if (l[0] is T) return true; // only try to access to check element
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
  return false;
}

void main() {
  List list = ['string', 'other string'];
  print(listElementIs<String>(list)); // prints 'true'
  print(listElementIs<int>(list)); // prints 'false'
}
```